# get OneToOneField data from User models on firsttime save()

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i want to extend my User models and add fields to it in another models

and i want it to save two of the form at once

each form works fine on its own but
the problem is that when i combine them the 
i cant get the username from the User model

```
class Information(models.Model):
    Username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

i tried this views.py

```
RegisterForm = self.form_class(request.POST)
InfoForm = self.second_form_class(request.POST)

if RegisterForm.is_valid() and InfoForm.is_valid():
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')

    User_obj = User(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name,
                        last_name=last_name)
    user = User_obj.save()

    Username = username 
    PhoneNo = request.POST.get('PhoneNo')
    Address = request.POST.get('Address')
    Country = request.POST.get('Country')
    Info_obj = Information(Username=Username , PhoneNo=PhoneNo, Address=Address, Country=Country)
    Info_obj.save()
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username","password", "email", "first_name", "last_name"]


class InfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Username = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Information
        fields = ["Username","PhoneNo","Address","Country"]
```

did i miss something here?
it can save to the User but it doesn't save to Information model

I think the problem is with the Username on InfoForm

Comment: why don't you save them one after the other?

Comment: what i think is that the user might bypass one of the form, like somehow save to models.User but not models.Information or the other way round @Bernard Parah

Comment: `user = User_obj.save(commit=False)` and then save ` user = User_obj.save()` just before the info save

Comment: @BernardParah thanks for the response,  have found the solution, Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was with the InfoForm's Username field

instead of directly getting the value from the RegisterForm

```
username = request.POST.get('username')

# with this code below Django demands that i need username instance from User model
Username = username
```

so after saving RegisterForm, i get the value from the User Database with a objects.get() method

```
Username = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

Solution

```
RegisterForm = self.form_class(request.POST)
InfoForm = self.second_form_class(request.POST)

if RegisterForm.is_valid() and InfoForm.is_valid():
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
    last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')

    User_obj = User(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name,
                        last_name=last_name)
    User_obj.save()

    # i call the username from the User database after saving them
    Username = User.objects.get(username=username)
    PhoneNo = request.POST.get('PhoneNo')
    Address = request.POST.get('Address')
    Country = request.POST.get('Country')
    Info_obj = Information(Username=Username , PhoneNo=PhoneNo, Address=Address, Country=Country)
    Info_obj.save()
```

don't know if i had explained it correctly

Cheers

Comment: Can you state where the problem was and how you fixed it?